# How to Mask Operations openCV - Frequency masking

Tags: image, opencv, filter, processing, mask

I would like to create a frequency mask in openCV but have no idea how to go about it. The frequency mask will be an ideal bandpass filter so image filtering will be done in the frequency domain. For this example lets say frequencies between 100Hz-200Hz will be coupled.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Perform DFT of your image.
2. Make an filter matrix with size of your image, where you have ring with radius R1 = wavelength_min, R2=wavelength_max. Ring is filled with ones and the rest elements are zeros.
3. Multiply DFT of your image by this matrix.
4. Perform inverse DFT of obtained image.

Comment: I can't vote you up so I will give you my full gratitude and will be forever thankful

Comment: You can approve the answer :)